# php namespaces,accessing global classes

Tags: php, namespaces

From the php documentation,we access global classes like

```
<?php
namespace A\B\C;
class Exception extends \Exception {}
$a = new Exception('hi'); // $a is an object of class A\B\C\Exception
$b = new \Exception('hi'); // $b is an object of class Exception
$c = new ArrayObject; // fatal error, class A\B\C\ArrayObject not found
?>
```

However,i am a lost when the doc says that

```
<?php
$a = new \stdClass;
?>
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
<?php
$a = new stdClass;
?>
```

here http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.shouldicare

Can someone kindly explain what the doc is saying here.

Thanks.

Comment: They are only equivalent, if you do not use namespaces yourself. (Because then, everything is declared in the global namespace `\\`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right above those two code examples [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.shouldicare) is the important heading:

> **If I don't use namespaces, should I care about any of this?**
>
> No. Namespaces do not affect any existing code in any way, or any as-yet-to-be-written code that does not contain namespaces. You can write this code if you wish:

So the implication here is not that you can write `new stdClass;` *inside* a namespace and have it be equivalent, but rather that if you are *not using namespaces at all*, then you needn't worry about the backslash `new \stdClass;`

When working in a namespace, the rule does apply and you will need to use `new \stdClass;`.

And this doesn't just apply to the generic `stdClass`, but to *any* class.

```
// Without namespaces:
$mysqli = new MySQLi(...);

// With namespaces
$mysqli = new \MySQLi(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says that `\stdClass` is functionally equivalent to `stdClass` only in:

> as-yet-to-be-written code **that does not contain** namespaces

I.e. if you are using namespaces - as your code indicates - you will have you define the class within the current namespace (to use `new stdClass`); or you will just have to use the native class which does not require one (`new \stdClass`).